# Is java.text.BreakIterator thread-safe in openjdk?

Tags: thread-safety, java

I ran into some weird threading issues in a continuous integration build on [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/Softhouse/jargo/jobs/6833381) and got:

```
    testThatDifferentArgumentsCanBeParsedConcurrently(se.softhouse.jargo.concurrency.ConcurrencyTest) Time elapsed: 0.479 sec <<< FAILURE!

org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<... greeting phrase to [

]greet new connection...> but was:<... greeting phrase to []greet new connection...>:<... greeting phrase to []greet new connection...>
```

It only seems to go wrong with openjdk and not with oraclejdk.

And [here's](https://github.com/Softhouse/jargo/blob/master/jargo/src/main/java/se/softhouse/common/strings/Lines.java) my code that's using BreakIterator:

```
/**
* Wraps lines where <a
* href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/line.html">appropriate</a> (as defined
* by {@code locale}).
*
* @param value the value to separate with {@link StringsUtil#NEWLINE new lines}
* @param startingIndex the index where each line starts, useful for a fixed-size table for
* instance
* @param maxLineLength how long each line are allowed to be
*/
public static StringBuilder wrap(CharSequence value, int startingIndex, int maxLineLength, Locale locale)
{
    String textToSplit = value.toString();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(textToSplit.length());
    // TODO(jontejj): is this not thread safe?
    BreakIterator boundary = BreakIterator.getLineInstance(locale);
    boundary.setText(textToSplit);
    int start = boundary.first();
    int end = boundary.next();
    int lineLength = startingIndex;

    while(end != BreakIterator.DONE)
    {
        String word = textToSplit.substring(start, end);
        lineLength = lineLength + word.length();
        if(lineLength >= maxLineLength)
        {
            result.append(NEWLINE);
            lineLength = startingIndex;
        }
        result.append(word);
        start = end;
        end = boundary.next();
    }
    return result;
}
```

It seems like java.text.BreakIterator didn't do it's job and stretched the line for more characters than it should have.

I checked the openjdk version of both BreakIterator and RuleBasedBreakIterator but couldn't identify any apparent thread safety issues. There are some arrays in RuleBasedBreakIterator that aren't deeply cloned but I couldn't see that they are modified so that should be safe. I could not find the oraclejdk source code. Have I understood it wrong that there shouldn't be as big differences between them as there used to be?

I tried to [isolate](https://github.com/Softhouse/jargo/blob/master/jargo/src/test/java/se/softhouse/common/strings/LinesTest.java) the issue with a specific test for BreakIterator usage but so far that hasn't been fruitful.

Sorry for the kind of awkward question but I'm at a standstill so I thought that maybe someone on stackoverflow could help.

Comment: You are creating a new, local BreakIterator in your method, so thread safety isn't an issue.

Comment: It 'only seems to go wrong with openJDK' or **does it finally** go wrong only with openJDK?

Comment: @VGR that's what I thought too, but then I got the error...

Comment: @home As with any thread safety issues, I've only confirmed the issue with openjdk. There may be issues with the oraclejdk as well, just that they aren't as easy to confirm.

Comment: btw, I recreated the issue a couple of times with my own ubuntu installation (through VirtualBox) and OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.5) (6b27-1.12.5-1ubuntu1) and when I used my own splitter it didn't occur anymore but as I'd like the features the BreakIterator provides I thought to ask.

Comment: @jontejj: fair enough. btw - my JSE7 source uses a cache (`private static BreakIterator getBreakInstance`), internally performing a `clone` on a given instance. I cannot answer your question, but there seems to be at least a risk as it depends how subclasses implement clone (e.g. handling instance variables).

Comment: Exactly, I looked at RuleBasedBreakIterator as that's what's being used in my case. Came up empty though. I think the intent is that getXXXInstance should be callable from multiple threads at least.